# make a smooth 3D matrix in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching

I have 3D matrix, and I want to remove some discntinuities and I want to change the statistical properties. I mean, I don't want to change the global statistical properties.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have the following result using a self-made algorithm :
[image]

The idea is the following :

- We first detect the discontinuities using edge detection, summing the result among both directions and thresholding.
- We create two images from this : one with lines in each direciton.
- We create two low-pass versions of the original image using a 1D gaussian filter : one filtered in each direction.
- We also low-pass filter the images containing the lines : they will be used as weights.
- We compose the final image by computing : (low-pass_line_image) .* filtered_image + (1 - low-pass_line_image) .* original_image. We perform this in both directions.

Here is the code :

```
    % Load and treat image
    im = imread('...');
    im = im2double(im);
    im = rgb2gray(im);

    % Compute edges of the image
    bw = edge(im);

    % We want to find the positions of the strong lines in the image :
    % Since they go through the whole image, we sum among x and y directions
    % and then threshold.
    xedges = sum(bw);
    xedges = xedges > 1/3*max(xedges(:));
    yedges = sum(bw,2);
    yedges = yedges > 1/3*max(yedges(:));

    % We create images of the same size that the original one and containing
    % the horizontal and vertical lines
    [xedges, yedges] = meshgrid(xedges, yedges);

    % We create a 1D gaussian filter
    gaussian = gausswin(12);
    gaussian = gaussian / sum(gaussian);

    % We filter the image among both directions
    imfy = imfilter(im, gaussian);
    imfx = imfilter(im, gaussian');

    % We also filter the images with the lines to get the weights
    xedges = im2double(xedges);
    xedges = imfilter(xedges, gaussian');
    xedges = xedges / max(xedges(:));
    yedges = im2double(yedges);
    yedges = imfilter(yedges, gaussian);
    yedges = yedges / max(yedges(:));

    % We use the filtered versions of the images with lines as weights between
    % the original image and the filtered images
    imfinal = xedges.*imfx + (1-xedges).*im;
    imfinal = yedges.*imfy + (1-yedges).*imfinal;
    imshow(imfinal);
```

Comment: Can this method be used for 3D matrix (let say 50x50x20)?

Comment: It does not work for 2D images (not rgb) and gives me a NaN matrix!

Comment: If you think of cubes being put side by side and you want to smooth at the boundaries between them, it can be generalize. The only tricky part is the edge detection (the matlab "edge" function does only work in 2D). [This can be helpful](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38366-three-dimensional-implementation-of-the-canny-edge-detection)

Comment: I tried with several grayscale images, but I don't get a NaN matrix. Can you tell me at which line computed matrices begin to contain NaN elements ? Maybe adapting the parameters (thresholds, window size of the gaussian) can help.

Comment: we I run     yedges = yedges / max(yedges(:)); I got NaN matrix!

Comment: Ok, I see. The threshold value is too high. No value of `yedges` is above it. Thus afterwards dividing by the max is like dividing by zero. Try to replace `xedges = xedges > 30;` by `xedges = xedges > 1/3*max(xedges(:));` and `yedges = yedges > 30;` by `yedges = yedges > 1/3*max(yedges(:));`. It should thus be OK with every image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use the texture synthesis algorithm proposed by Efros et al:

http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/people/efros/research/EfrosLeung.html

Comment: I tested that algorithm , but I still have discontinuity. Is there any algorithm?